# Is it possible to extend stylus using javascript?

Tags: javascript, stylus

I am well aware of mixins feature of [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus). But the language features available seem to be quite limited.

In sass, you can write a function in ruby and make them available directly to sass. So the full power of ruby language is available to mixin author.

Is there an API available for doing something similar with stylus ?

Some interesting use cases would be mixins which can manipulate colors, generate complex gradients etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function in JavaScript and make it available in Stylus in much the same way as ruby/sass.  See the docs [here](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html).

you want the section about .define(name, fn)